# ADB Interface driver for Sony Xperia M4 Aqua

Tags: user-interface

I have Sony Xperia M4 Aqua. I'm trying to connect it through data cable with my HP laptop having Vista OS. When I connect like this, laptop search for ADB Interface but is not able to find. I tried searching all around google bur couldn't find anywhere. Please help me locate the site from where I can download exact driver.

Answer (score 0):

The google search for "xperia m4 aqua adb drivers" shows [this XDA forums page](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=61227900&postcount=3) as the first result, and it has download links to ADB driver packages for your phone.

1. Windows Update may download them automatically
2. Use [Google's own ADB drivers](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/latest_usb_driver_windows.zip)
3. Use [Universal ADB Drivers](http://adbdriver.com/upload/AdbDriverInstaller.exe)
4. Use Sony's ADB Drivers (see XDA post for attachment)
5. Use [Flashtool](http://www.flashtool.net) to install ADB, fastboot and flashtool All-In-One

Comment: None is working for me (On Windows 10)

Comment: By the way, with viruses in the provided files moreover

Comment: @Hithredin Could you specify which files, so I can edit the link out of the answer?

Comment: Not sure, but it seems to be the flashtool. It had configured a local proxy to capture all the network request, redirect sometimes to advert pages and blocked antivirus update.

Comment: @Hithredin I scanned them all with VirusTotal, no real detections. Haven't heard about that kind of malware, but some root exploits are detected as false positives occasionally.